# How to update element of an array in MongoDB By PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a collection named 'question'. Its structure looks like this:

```
{
     _id:
     user_id:
     answers:
     [
          {
               answer_id:
               answer_content:
          }  
           ,
          {
            ...
          }
          ,
           ...
      ]
}
```

Now I know the document's _id and answer_id of one answer，now I want to set the answer to 
be a best_answer(add a field to the element) for example:

```
{
    answer_id:
    answer_content:
    is_best:true
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to do an update or an insert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$find_array = array('answers._id'=>$answer_id); 
$this>collection>update($find_array,array('$set'=>array('answers.$.is_best' => true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the question document in the questions collection, one way is to $push the user info onto a answeredBy array field of some sort.  Alternately you could create a separate answers collection and push answer documents containing the question id, uid, name, and answer.

Comment: $find_array = array('answers._id'=>$answer_id);
    
    $user_info_array = array('uid'=>$user_id,'name'=>$user_name);
    
    $this->collection->update($find_array,array('$push'=>array('answers.$.like'=>$user_info_array)));